# How to respond to a Teams card using Power automate?

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, adaptive-cards

I am trying to create a Power automate flow that send messages to a chatbot and respond to card sent by the bot.

So far I am able to send message to the bot using power automate (using Post message in a chat or channel) to trigger the chatbot in which it respond by sending a card demanding input from the user.

[image]

There are 4 option to select in the card.
But not able to find any material to give respond (select option) in the card via Power automate.

Most of the them regarding posting the card and getting the response via power automate.

I have also tried to respond with regular message mentioning one of the option but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Input.ChoiceSet control. With the current style you should be able to select an option in the dropdown.

You can also change the style to expanded, this will display the choiceset different:
https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.ChoiceSet.html

To submit your data you can use a Action.Submit control:
https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.Submit.html

Have a look at one of the Microsoft examples in the docs, the Candidate feedback sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/candidate-feedback-sample